# Bootstrap 3 close nav menu when you click outside

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am using the following jQuery:

```
            jQuery(document).click(function (event) {
               var clickover = jQuery(event.target);
               var _opened = jQuery(".navbar-collapse2").hasClass("in");
               if (_opened === true && !clickover.hasClass("navbar-toggle")) {
                  jQuery("button.navbar-toggle").click();
               }
            });
```

The problem is within navbar-collapse I have some sub menus and when I click to expand/collapse them. It also collapses the main nav menu.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably check if your clicked element is not a child of `.navbar-toggle`. You can do that with the `closest()` function. This will find the first parent that matches the selector.

```
if (_opened === true && !clickover.hasClass("navbar-toggle") && clickover.closest(".navbar-toggle").length === 0)
```